data from database- sqlite table not displayed in python pyqt5
i am using python and sqlite3 with pyqt5, i designed form in pypt5 designer converting it to py xml file and connecting to sqlite database table called "teacher" , i fed in the data in the table and created 15 rows, when i run the program call_teacher, the data from table is not displayed in the tablewidgets. i have tried to troubleshoot with print command to view the values it works and displays in the backgound, but my problem is the data is not being displayed in the tablewidgets. please help me i am new to this.
# call_teacher.py
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from datetime import datetime
db_file =r"c:\sqlite3\school.db"
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem
from gui_school import *


class TeacherForm(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QDialog, self).__init__()
        self.ui= Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pbShowTeacher.clicked.connect(self.show_teacher_data)
        self.show()
       # self.show_teacher_data()
    def show_teacher_data(self):
        # clean Table
        print("button pushed")
        self.ui.twTeacher.clear()
        # populate tables
        col =['Teacher ID','Complete Name','Date of Birth',\
              'Gender','Blood Type','Address','Telephone','Email',\
                'Password','Photo Path']
        self.ui.twTeacher.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(col)
             
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM Teacher"

        cur.execute(sqlstr)
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        #print(rows)
        rc = cur.rowcount
        xx = len(sqlstr)       
        noRow = 0
        
        for tuple in rows:
            noCol=0
            
            for column in tuple:
               satuKolom=QTableWidgetItem(str(column))
               print(column)
               print(noCol)
               self.ui.twTeacher.setItem(noRow,noCol,satuKolom)
               # self.ui.twTeacher.setItem(noRow,noCol,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(column[0]))
               noCol+=1
            noRow+=1
        
    
        print(noRow)
       # conn.commit()
      #  conn.close()
if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TeacherForm()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

#### gui_school.py as xml
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'gui_school.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.9
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(963, 569)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 10, 101, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 50, 61, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 80, 81, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 110, 81, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 150, 47, 13))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 150, 61, 16))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 190, 47, 13))
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 230, 51, 16))
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 270, 47, 13))
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 270, 47, 13))
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.labelPhoto = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.labelPhoto.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 210, 121, 16))
        self.labelPhoto.setObjectName("labelPhoto")
        self.leTeacherID = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.leTeacherID.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 50, 113, 20))
        self.leTeacherID.setObjectName("leTeacherID")
        self.leTeacherName = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.leTeacherName.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 80, 191, 20))
        self.leTeacherName.setObjectName("leTeacherName")
        self.leTeacherGender = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.leTeacherGender.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 150, 113, 20))
        self.leTeacherGender.setObjectName("leTeacherGender")
        self.leTeacherBlood = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.leTeacherBlood.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 150, 71, 20))
        self.leTeacherBlood.setObjectName("leTeacherBlood")
        self.leTeacherAddress = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.leTeacherAddress.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 190, 201, 20))
        self.leTeacherAddress.setObjectName("leTeacherAddress")
        self.leTeacherTelephone = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.leTeacherTelephone.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 230, 113, 20))
        self.leTeacherTelephone.setObjectName("leTeacherTelephone")
        self.leTeacherEmail = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.leTeacherEmail.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 270, 113, 20))
        self.leTeacherEmail.setObjectName("leTeacherEmail")
        self.leTeacherPassword = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.leTeacherPassword.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 270, 113, 20))
        self.leTeacherPassword.setObjectName("leTeacherPassword")
        self.pbFirst = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pbFirst.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 300, 75, 23))
        self.pbFirst.setObjectName("pbFirst")
        self.pbPrevious = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pbPrevious.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 300, 75, 23))
        self.pbPrevious.setObjectName("pbPrevious")
        self.pbNext = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pbNext.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 300, 75, 23))
        self.pbNext.setObjectName("pbNext")
        self.pbLast = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pbLast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 300, 75, 23))
        self.pbLast.setObjectName("pbLast")
        self.pbShowTeacher = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pbShowTeacher.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 330, 161, 31))
        self.pbShowTeacher.setObjectName("pbShowTeacher")
        self.deTeacherBirth = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(Dialog)
        self.deTeacherBirth.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 110, 110, 22))
        self.deTeacherBirth.setObjectName("deTeacherBirth")
        self.twTeacher = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Dialog)
        self.twTeacher.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 360, 781, 192))
        self.twTeacher.setColumnCount(10)
        self.twTeacher.setObjectName("twTeacher")
        self.twTeacher.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.twTeacher.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.twTeacher.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.twTeacher.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.twTeacher.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.twTeacher.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.twTeacher.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.twTeacher.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.twTeacher.setHorizontalHeaderItem(7, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.twTeacher.setHorizontalHeaderItem(8, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.twTeacher.setHorizontalHeaderItem(9, item)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.pbShowTeacher.clicked.connect(self.twTeacher.showFullScreen) # type: ignore
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Teacher Information"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Teacher ID"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Complete Name"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Date Of Birth"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Gender"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Blood Type"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Address"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Telephone"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Email"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Password"))
        self.labelPhoto.setText(_translate("Dialog", "SHOW TEACHER\'S DATA"))
        self.pbFirst.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<<"))
        self.pbPrevious.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<"))
        self.pbNext.setText(_translate("Dialog", ">"))
        self.pbLast.setText(_translate("Dialog", ">>"))
        self.pbShowTeacher.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Show All Teacher Data"))
        item = self.twTeacher.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Dialog", "New Column"))
        item = self.twTeacher.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Dialog", "ID"))
        item = self.twTeacher.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Name"))
        item = self.twTeacher.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Dialog", "DOB"))
        item = self.twTeacher.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Gender"))
        item = self.twTeacher.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Blood Type"))
        item = self.twTeacher.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Address"))
        item = self.twTeacher.horizontalHeaderItem(7)
        item.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Telephone"))
        item = self.twTeacher.horizontalHeaderItem(8)
        item.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Email"))
        item = self.twTeacher.horizontalHeaderItem(9)
        item.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Photo"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



You're not setting the row count on the table. Add self.ui.twTeacher.setRowCount(len(rows)) before entering the for loop. You also don't need to use the backslash character for new lines within parentheses, and calling a variable tuple is a terrible idea, since it's a Built-in function.

Sir, i also had a doubt about using Tuple as a variable but i am following the book "Python GUI with SQL Server for Absolute Beginners" by Vivian Siahaan and Rismon, i will try now the recommendation you made and shall update you

The solution you gave above is working perfectly now. thank you very much

I had a quick look on Google books. Besides many typos and errors, there are serious issues in terminology (starting with the fact that they don't make a distinction between events and signals), various inconsistencies, confusing and approximate coverage of widgets (with no mention about proper usage of layout managers, which is very important) and poor choices in syntax and naming (including the usage of tuple above, which is a terrible suggestion, especially for beginners). I'd suggest you to look for other resources, that's not a reliable reference book.

Very much thanks for your support and guidance, definitely i will look for other resources - Regards Siraj

I have found a book "Python GUI with PyQt5" by Saurabh Chandrakar , ordered through online
